# Authorization object S_NUMBER

Tags: sap-basis

What difference is there between activity `02` and activity `17`?

> `02` Create/change/delete number range intervals
> `17` Create/change/delete number range objects

I read somewhere that this one and too.

Answer (score 2):

a SAP number range object can have different number range intervals.

- 02 is for intervals
- 17 is for objects

hava a look at this SAP help entry about number ranges objects and intervals: [Number Ranges - Concept](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/48/d58f92982b424be10000000a421937/frameset.htm)